# Rename file - delete all characters AFTER 2nd underscore

Tags: powershell

I need to replace the time\date stamp that's included in the filename after 2nd underscore (needs to be in the same format `yyyyMMddHHmmss`)

example file: `123456_123456_20190716163001.xml`

sometimes the file in question gets created with an additional character which invalidates the file, in this case I need to replace this with the current timestamp.

example: `123456_123456_current Timestamp here.xml`

The file should never exceed 32 characters(including extension)

I found a script but it deletes everything after the 1st underscore not the 2nd and I'm struggling to find a way to replace the text with the current timestamp.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\test -Filter 123456_123456*.xml | Foreach-Object -Process { 
    $NewName = [Regex]::Match($_.Name,"^[^_]*").Value + '.xml' $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName 
}
```

timestamp after 2nd underscore to be updated to the current timestamp if original file exceeds 32 characters

`123456_123456_current Timestamp here.xml`

Comment: Get-ChildItem c:\test -Filter 123456_123456*.xml | Foreach-Object  -Process { 
    $NewName = [Regex]::Match($_.Name,"^[^_]*").Value + '.xml'
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}

Comment: Hi, please click "edit" under your question to add that PowerShell code into the question, rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, cant seem to get the formatting correct on the post.

Comment: It's alright. If you need assistance with formatting, you can click the `?` icon on the edit page (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyxMM.png).

Answer (score 0):

this takes advantage of the way a `[fileinfo]` object is structured. the `.BaseName` is easy to get to & use `.Split()` on. then one can use `-join` to put it back into one basename & finally add the extension onto the basename.

```
# fake reading in a file info object
#    in real life, use Get-ChildItem or Get-Item
$FileObject = [System.IO.FileInfo]'123456_123456_current Timestamp here.xml'

$NewName = -join (($FileObject.BaseName.Split('_')[0,1] -join '_'), $FileObject.Extension)

$NewName
```

output = `123456_123456.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the regex theme, you can do the following:

```
$CurrentTime = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'
$RegexReplace = "(.*?_.*?_).*(\..*)"
Get-ChildItem c:\test -Filter 123456_123456*.xml |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $RegexReplace,"`${1}$CurrentTime`${2}"}
```

If duplicate file names are a concern, you can build in an increment to `$CurrentTime`.

```
$CurrentTime = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'
$RegexReplace = "(.*?_.*?_).*(\..*)"
Get-ChildItem c:\test -Filter 123456_123456*.xml |
Rename-Item -NewName {
    $NewName = $_.Name -replace $RegexReplace,"`${1}$CurrentTime`${2}"
    if (test-path $NewName) {
        $CurrentTime = [double]$CurrentTime + 1
        $NewName = $_.Name -replace $RegexReplace,"`${1}$CurrentTime`${2}"
    }
    $NewName
}
```

**Explanation:**

`$RegexReplace` contains the regex expression that will need to be matched for the ideal rename operation to happen. The regex mechanisms are explained below:

- `.*?_.*?_`: Matches a minimal number of characters (lazy matching) followed by an underscore and then another minimal number of characters followed by an underscore.
- `.*`: Greedily matches any characters
- `\.`: Literally matches the dot character (`.`).
- `()`: The parentheses here represent capture groups with the first set being 1 and the second set being 2. These are later referenced as `${1}` and `${2}` in the `-replace` operation.

Since `Rename-Item -NewName` supports delayed script binding, we can just pipe `Get-ChildItem` output directly to it. The current pipeline object is `$_`.

The `-replace` operation uses the variable `$CurrentTime`, which must be expanded in order for a successful outcome. For that reason, we use double quotes around the replacement. Since we do not want capture groups `${1}` and `${2}` expanded, we backtick escape them.

Comment: This script is great, the only problem is when multiple files exist it can't rename the file because it already exists. Is there a way to add a slight delay for each file?

Comment: I added some secondary code to handle that case if you need it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this, I really like the detailed explanation too. there can be anywhere from 1 -10 files in the directory, I'm getting errors still when running the amended script.